# Why does fetch return a weird hash of integers?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch` API with React Native.

My response follows a normal format of `{"message": "error here"}` if the status is >= 400, which I will show in a native popup.

I'm trying to call `response.json()` after detecting a failure, but it keeps putting everything in a weird format...

`{ _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }`

For whatever reason... the actual response I want is located in `_65`... I have no idea what these random keys are.

So currently I'm having to access it via `_bodyText`, but I assume that is wrong because it's a private underscore method.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var API = (function() {

  var base = 'https://example.com/api/v1';

  var defaults = {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  var alertFailure = function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 400) {
      return response;
    } else {
      var json = JSON.parse(response._bodyText || '{}');
      var message = json.message || 'There was a problem. Close the app, and try again later.';

      var error = new Error(message);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  };

  var callAPI = function(url, opts) {
    opts.headers['X-Version'] = 'v' + Package.version;

    return fetch(base + url, opts)
      .then(alertFailure)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(null, error.message);
      });
  };

  return {

    get: function(url, opts) {
      var fullOpts = Object.assign({}, defaults, opts);
      return callAPI(url, fullOpts);
    },

    post: function(url, data, opts) {
      var fullOpts = Object.assign({}, defaults, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data || {})
      }, opts);
      return callAPI(url, fullOpts);
    }
  };

})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that `.json()` returns a promise... so I had to do everything from within `.then()`

Comment: This is also the same for `asyncstorage`

Comment: Just ran into same problem with `async` and `await`. Still trying to resolve it.

Comment: I added my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285564/why-does-fetch-return-a-weird-hash-of-integers-part-2

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage.getItems always returns a promise. You can use this method below

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem("access_key").then((value)=>
               {
                    console.log(value);
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the new ES7 syntax `async/await`, they are easier to understand than using `.then()`

To use it, just declare some method with the async prefix and inside of it use await to wait for the call to finish.

E.g

```
async someMethod(){
    result =  await fetch(URL); // Do some request to any API.
    // Use the result after that knowing that you'll have it completed. 
}
```

I hope this helps, at least in my opinion, I find this easier than using .then(), especially when you have to do multiple calls within the same method.