# Why does fetch return a weird hash of integers - part 2?

Tags: async-await, react-native, fetch, es6-promise

I'm using `async/await` with React Native.

My result from `response.json()` is:
{ _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }

For whatever reason, the actual response I want is located in _65 and I have no idea what these random keys are.

It seems that it is related to the fact that `.json()` returns a Promise.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData().then(data => this.setState({ data }))
  }
  async getData() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(myUrl)
      let json = await response.json()
      return json
    } catch(err) {
      Alert.alert(null, err)
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state
  ...
```

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539743/why-does-fetch-return-a-weird-hash-of-integers

Comment: The answer is:
```this.getData().then(data => this.setState({ data }))```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: this.getData().then(data => this.setState({ data }))

Comment: But what should I do if this doesn't meet my needs and I really need async/await? How to fix it?